# Mudar cor de um botão e que ele se mantenha mudado após o usuário sair e retornar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Será que existe alguma maneira de fazer com que uma página mantenha a mudança de cor de um botão (ou link) com uma função como o "a:visited" do CSS mas esse mudança deve permanecer mesmo depois do usuário sair do site e retornar depois?

Comment: Acredito que você terá que usar algum meio para guardar esta informação, um banco de dados seria ideal, ou pelo menos um `COOKIE` que por sua vez limitaria o tempo que a informação ficaria armazenada.

Comment: cookie resolve sim, eu tenho cookies gravados aqui de vários sites há anos e funcionam perfeitamente. Só o pessoal que tem pinimba com cookies que não vai dar certo pois ficam deletando a torto e a direito. Então, se for para usuarios que fazem login, pode guardar essa configuração no banco que sempre vai dar certo quando ele se logar, o que também não é o desejavel. O desejavel seria sempre, logado ou deslogado

Answer (score 0):

Como o que você quer fazer não envolve questões de segurança, quer apenas alterar o estilo de um botão, você pode usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) do JavaScript, que funciona como um *cookie*.

O `localStorage` guarda uma informação no navegador em uma variável que pode ser recuperada a qualquer tempo, e essa informação não se apaga quando na saída do site ou quando o navegador é fechado.

**Definindo um `localStorage`**

Você pode criar de forma direta usando a sintaxe:

```
localStorage.botao = "algum_valor";
```

Onde `botao` é o nome dado ao `localStorage` e `algum_valor` é o valor dele. Você pode colocar um valor específico que poderá ser usado posteriormente ou simplesmente setar `true`, apenas para indicar que ele existe:

```
localStorage.botao = true;
```

> Vale lembrar que ao colocar `localStorage.botao = false;` não servirá
>   para checagem *booleana*, ou seja, `localStorage.botao = true;` e
>   `localStorage.botao = false;` irá retornar verdadeiro em
>   `if(localStorage.botao)`. Isso porque **não** se está verificando seu valor,
>   mas sim se ele existe.

**Voltando ao raciocínio...**

Supondo que você possua 2 `class` no seu CSS, uma para cada cor do botão:

```
.botao_vermelho{
    background: red;
}

.botao_verde{
    background: green;
}
```

Ao alterar a cor do botão de *vermelho* para *verde* e deseja que o usuário tenha sempre o botão *verde* ao retornar ao site, crie o `localStorage.botao = true;` e insira no seu código a verificação abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var button = $("#id_do_botao"); // pego o botão pelo id
    if(localStorage.botao){ // verifico se o localStorage "botao" existe

        // removo a class vermelho e adiciono a verde
        button.addClass("botao_verde")
        .removeClass("botao_vermelho");
    }
});
```

**Removendo o `localStorage`**

Depois de criado, o `localStorage` não tem prazo para expirar. Ele só será excluído via opção no navegador, se o mesmo for desinstalado ou pela instrução abaixo:

```
localStorage.removeItem("botao");
```

Portanto, quando não precisar mais dele, insira a linha acima na parte do seu código onde deseja fazer isso.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Será que não daria para fazer essa função expirar em um determinado prazo, por exemplo, 24 horas?

Comment: @Mr.Cranium Sim, você pode se basear neste [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c94z0x3o/).